# "seeing something" means "seeing things in general"?

Tags: pronouns

**Example:**

> I don't want to put too much stress on my eyes. So, I don't put a lot of effort into the action of **seeing something**.

**Question:**

I want to talk about the action of seeing things in general. Can I use **something** this way like in the example to convey the meaning of seeing things in general?

Comment: You can state "the action of seeing something"  more concisely as "my vision".

Comment: If you wanted to avoid stressing your eyes, it'd make more sense to say what you were actively doing, or actively avoiding to achieve that goal. Saying that you don't put a lot of effort into it makes you sound lazy or that you just don't care about your vision -- that's not what you mean, right?

Comment: "...seeing **things**" is more natural than "seeing something"

Answer (score 1):

The verb you want is "look" rather than "see": you cannot really control whether you see something or not, either you do or you don't, but you can control the extent to which you look at it: a brief glance, a long look, an intense stare.

Your example would therefore read "I don't want to put too much stress on my eyes. So, I don't put a lot of effort into the action of looking at something."

Having said that, while the use of "something" is OK, the two sentences do not read very naturally in English, especially the "I do not put a lot of effort onto." I would suggest something like

"I don't want to stress my eyes too much, so I don't look at things too intensely."